# How can I create text that is human readable but not machine readable in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am making a simple mental math training app at https://mattea.app/. It is a timed competition, and I measure the time you spend answering 10 exercises.

The exercises are made on the server - in Node.js function served through Google Firebase Cloud Functions.

One problem is that users can cheat by making a script that read the exercises and then programmatically calculate and submit the answers really quick. To make this harder, I return the execise as an SVG-tag, but each number turns into the same output each time, so it is not so hard to crack.

How can the Node.js function return the exercise text (for instance "9x8") in format that is human readable but not so easily machine-readable?

Comment: As a quick idea it comes to my mind that you can return an image. Take a look at this module: https://www.npmjs.com/package/text2png. It converts texts into PNG. After creating a PNG you would need to store that image in a public folder and then send the path to the client in order to load it in an `<img>`.

Comment: in a simple example like that "nine multiplied by eight" is marginally harder for a machine to read. Probably outputting the question text within an image (like a captcha) is your best bet though.

Comment: Since “machine readable” is a superset of “human readable” when it comes to simple strings, I would suggest some kind of encryption mechanism. Having said that, I can’t seem to find a good, unknown to the user, key. Any kind of encryption based on client-side decryption can be bypassed easily with common web-dev knowledge.

Comment: Use a random number of [zero-width space unicode characters (U+200B)](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200B/index.htm) around the visible characters. Not hard to crack, but at least it provides a little extra work to do so.

Comment: You say this is a training app, but at the same time programmed solvers are a problem? What's the actual issue here?

Comment: The issue is people outside the target group that want to sabotage.

Comment: Also, why not employ [rate limiting](https://blog.apisyouwonthate.com/what-is-api-rate-limiting-all-about-1819a390ab06)? You could determine the maximum speed a human could possibly achieve, and if that's exceeded, you know it's machine.

Comment: This question, however interesting, is just too broad to be ever effectively answered in my opinion. No matter how you approach this, you can never be certain. What if I use a bot to solve it, but I (human) wait to submit the answer and trick you? Additionally, this is a simple multiplication test. If anyone cheats on this, its on them. Given the grade this is targeted at, I don't think they can cheat easily, unless you target globally (re your global location stats). I think you are overdoing this, unless its a training ground for something more serious.

Comment: If you keep stats, you can later plot a chart and use some statistical analysis to see distribution of results, and remove extremes.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up converting the number to a SVG path. Later on I can add some randomness to the numbers in the path, so that it cannot easily be reversed. Of course this could be reversed by an OCR algorithm, but at least it makes it a bit more work to do.